# Display Sliqte data in listview with query

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, listview

I have an SQLite database of universities with a score. Each university has a unique score. here is the database code.

```
public class UniversityFinderDB {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 1;
static final String DATABASE_NAME="universities.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME="university";

private static final String COLUMN_UNIVID="univId";
private static final String COLUMN_UNIVERSITYNAME="univName";
private static final String COLUMN_SCORE="score";

SQLiteDatabase db;

Context context;


public void openDatabase(Context context, String database){
    this.context=context;
    db=this.context.openOrCreateDatabase(database,MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    createTable();
}

private void createTable() {
    String query="create table university (univId integer primary key  not null, univName varchar not null, score integer not null);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

public void executeEventInsert(){

    String query="INSERT INTO university (univName, score) VALUES('UCI',122);";
    String query1="INSERT INTO university (univName, score) VALUES('UMI',132);";
    String query2="INSERT INTO university (univName, score) VALUES('LLC',222);";
    String query3="INSERT INTO university (univName, score) VALUES('OIC',432);";
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.execSQL(query1);
    db.execSQL(query2);
    db.execSQL(query3);
}


public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> executeSelectEvents(int input){
    String query="select" +COLUMN_UNIVERSITYNAME+ "from"+TABLE_NAME+"where" +COLUMN_SCORE+" >="+input;
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(query,null);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> events=new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String,String> event=new HashMap<>();

        String colUniversityId=cursor.getColumnName(0);
        String colUniversityIdValue=cursor.getString(0);
        String  colUniversityName=cursor.getColumnName(1);
        String colUniversityValue=cursor.getString(1);


        event.put(colUniversityId,colUniversityIdValue);
        event.put(colUniversityName,colUniversityValue);
        events.add(event);
    }
    return events;
}

}
```

Then I have a School finder activity class which has an edit text of score and a button. here is the XML file.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
    android:text="Gre:"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/shoot_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
    android:onClick="onClickUnivList"
    android:text="View Universities"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/greFinder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="72dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="96dp" />
```

The java class of this school finder is below

```
public class SchoolFinder extends AppCompatActivity {

UniversityFinderDB db;

EditText greScore;
Button submitButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_school_finder);

    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shoot_button);
    greScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.greFinder);
}
public void onClickUnivList(View view) {
    String gre = greScore.getText().toString();
    int greValue = Integer.parseInt(gre);
    Intent intent = new Intent(SchoolFinder.this, 
 ListviewFinderUniversities.class);
    intent.putExtra("Gre",greValue);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Listview class

```
 public class ListviewFinderUniversities extends AppCompatActivity {

UniversityFinderDB myDB;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventData;
ListView finderListview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview_finder_universities);




    finderListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.finderListView);
    myDB.openDatabase(getApplicationContext(),UniversityFinderDB.DATABASE_NAME);



    loadUnivFromDb();

}

private void createUnivAdapter(){
    String from[]={"univId","univName"};
    int to[] = {R.id.eventId, R.id.evenLabel};
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), eventData, R.layout.uni_item_finder, from, to);
    finderListview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void loadUnivFromDb() {
    int gre = getIntent().getIntExtra("Gre",0);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data= myDB.executeSelectEvents(gre);
    if(data.size()>0){
        eventData=data;
        createUnivAdapter();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NoEvents",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Now as soon as the user enters a score and press the submit button the application must show the list of universities whos score is above the number entered by the user in a new activity which has a listview. How do I add the query for this problem? Please help in new in programming trying to build my own project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> executeSelectEvents(int input){
    String query="select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where " +COLUMN_SCORE+" >= "+input;
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(query,null);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> events=new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String,String> event=new HashMap<>();

        String colUniversityId=cursor.getColumnName(0);
        String colUniversityIdValue=cursor.getString(0);
        String  colUniversityName=cursor.getColumnName(1);
        String colUniversityValue=cursor.getString(1);


        event.put(colUniversityId,colUniversityIdValue);
        event.put(colUniversityName,colUniversityValue);
        events.add(event);
    }
    return events;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I just want to add University Name in the Listview. How can I do that?